# failed processing manifest. Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

When I build my project I got this error;

> found.","sources":[{"file":"....\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":146}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   error: failed processing manifest.
>
> > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

I've been dealing with this error for a long time.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

update the compileSdkVersion to 23 in the build.gradle file

Comment: does not work it says resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.